# First Borel-Cantelli-Lemma - Two different proofs

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, borel-cantelli-lemmas

The Borel Cantelli Lemma states that for a sequence of events $(A_n)$ with finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_k)< \infty$ the probability of infinite many events happening is $0$, thus $P(\lim\sup_{n \to \infty} A_n)=0.$

Before getting to my question, here are two different proofs that make sense to me:

**First one:**

Let $B_m=\bigcup_{k \geq m}A_k$, then $\lim_{m \to \infty} B_m=\lim\sup_{n \to\infty}A_n$ from above. Hence, by the continuity, subadditivity of measures
$$P(\lim\sup_{n \to \infty} A_n)=P(\lim_{m \to \infty} B_m)=\lim_{m \to \infty}P( \bigcup_{k \geq m}A_k)\leq \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}P(A_k)=0.$$

**Second one:**

$P(\lim\sup_{n \to \infty} A_n)=0$ is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{A_k}(\omega) < \infty$. So we need to show that $P(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{A_k}(\omega))\geq \infty)=0$.
First of all, by linearity of the expectation we have $$E\bigl (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{A_k}\bigr )=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}E(1_{A_k})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_k) < \infty$$
Thus, by using Markov's inequality we obtain
$$P(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{A_k}(\omega) \geq \epsilon) \leq {1 \over \epsilon}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P(A_k) \rightarrow0$$ for $\epsilon \to \infty$ which completes the proof.

**Question:**

If both proofs are correct (please check), does any of those two proofs require something that is not needed in the other proof?

Comment: Both proofs are valid.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy IMO the second proof should be rewritten before it can be judged. The idea might be okay, but very weird things are said in that proof.

Comment: @drhab thanks for checking. Whats parts should be rewritten?

Comment: Start with looking at spots where your write an $\omega$ (so just one arbitrary outcome) and wonder whether it is on its place. E.g. we can talk about $\mathbb E1_A$ but not about $\mathbb E1_A(\omega)$.

Comment: Also note that $P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=0)\iff\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{A_k}(\omega)<\infty$ must become something like $\omega\notin\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n\iff\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1_{A_k}(\omega)<\infty$.

Comment: Okay thank you will think about it later